# Two-dimentional vector of Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I'm developing a system in C++ for comparing dynamic number of regions of interest(ROI) of a dynamic number of frames in a video(windowsize). For this reason I'm using a two dimensional vector of Mat, declared and initiated like this:

```
vector< vector<Mat> > ROIvector(numberofROI,vector<Mat>(windowsize));
```

The vector is filled with Mat from a video like this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<windowsize;i++)
        {
            video>>frame;
            if(frame.empty())
            {
                break;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<numberofROI;j++)
            {
                Mat temp;
                frame(ROIRectVector[j]).copyTo(temp);
                ROIvector[j].push_back(temp);
            }
        }
```

But whenever I try to access a single Mat, for instance ROIvector[0][3], openCV throws an exception of this type.

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file C:/slave/WinInstallerMegaPack/src/opencv/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
```

I'm not having trouble when accessing a one dimensional vector of Mat in the same manner, is there a problem with two dimensional ones?

Comment: Solved it, seems that my push_back() didn't work as I thought, a simpler ROIvector[j][i]=temp did the trick.

Comment: Add this comment as an answer and select it as the official answer to your question by clicking in the checkbox near it.